# wxPython StaticText won't resize when text changes

Tags: python, wxpython

I am having some sizing problems with my wxPython code.  I have a StaticText help message that can be either shown or hidden, and the message needs to change depending on the user mode.

What seems to happen by default is that the BoxSizer containing the StaticText correctly assumes the size of the StaticText the first time it is shown, but will not then re-size when the StaticText contents change.

My initial code looked like this (for context, the full code is at the end of my post):

```
        self.msg_text = wx.StaticText(self.panel, label=self.default_msg_text,
                                      style=wx.TE_CENTER | wx.EXPAND,
                                      name='help msg text’)
        self.help_msg_boxsizer.Add(self.msg_text, flag=wx.EXPAND)
        self.help_msg_boxsizer.ShowItems(False)
```

Then I tried setting the size manually:

```
        self.msg_text_size = (500, 100)
        self.msg_text = wx.StaticText(self.panel, label=self.default_msg_text,
                                      style=wx.TE_CENTER | wx.EXPAND,
                                      name='help msg text',
                                      size=self.msg_text_size)
        self.help_msg_boxsizer.Add(self.msg_text, flag=wx.EXPAND)
        self.help_msg_boxsizer.ShowItems(False)
```

and then using:

```
    self.msg_text.SetSize(new_size)
    # or
    self.help_msg_boxsizer.GetStaticBox.SetSize(new_size)
```

but neither of these lines seem to work.  Instead the initial size of (500, 100) seems to still be used no matter what.

I thought setting size hints might help, but it appears to have no effect:

```
    self.help_msg_boxsizer.SetSizeHints()
```

Lastly, the presence or absence of wx.EXPAND seems to make no difference.

To sum up: what I want to do is appropriately re-size `self.msg_text` to the minimum size required when shown.  How can I accomplish this?

Here is the full code to run my example:

```
import wx
import sys


class GridFrame(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self, frame_name="grid frame",
                 panel_name="grid panel", parent=None):
        title = 'Edit {} data'.format(panel_name)
        super(GridFrame, self).__init__(parent=parent, id=wx.ID_ANY,
                                        name=frame_name, title=title)
        self.remove_cols_mode = False
        self.panel = wx.Panel(self, name=panel_name)#, size=wx.GetDisplaySize())
        self.grid_type = str(panel_name)
        self.InitUI()


    ## Initialization functions
    def InitUI(self):
        """
        initialize window
        """
        self.main_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        set1 = []
        ## btns set 1
        for btn_name in ['btn1']:
            btn = wx.Button(self.panel, label=btn_name, name=btn_name)
            set1.append((btn))
        self.remove_cols_button = wx.Button(self.panel, label="Remove columns",
                                            name='remove_cols_btn')
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.on_remove_cols, self.remove_cols_button)

        ## Help message and button
        # button
        self.toggle_help_btn = wx.Button(self.panel, id=-1, label="Show help",
                                         name='toggle_help_btn')
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.toggle_help, self.toggle_help_btn)
        # message
        self.help_msg_boxsizer = wx.StaticBoxSizer(wx.StaticBox(self.panel, -1, name='help_msg_boxsizer'),
                                                   wx.VERTICAL)
        self.default_msg_text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec pulvinar, massa sit amet congue facilisis, augue nisl vehicula nulla, vel posuere ligula metus eu sapien. Nam vitae mauris nec turpis congue eleifend. Ut accumsan lorem risus, vitae scelerisque mi viverra at. In sit amet purus pretium, ultricies neque eget, ultricies enim. Aenean dignissim ornare mattis. Sed vitae consequat urna, et congue neque."
        self.msg_text_size = (500, 100)
        self.msg_text = wx.StaticText(self.panel, label=self.default_msg_text,
                                      style=wx.TE_CENTER | wx.EXPAND,
                                      name='help msg text',
                                      size=self.msg_text_size)
        self.help_msg_boxsizer.Add(self.msg_text, flag=wx.EXPAND)
        self.help_msg_boxsizer.SetSizeHints(self)
        self.help_msg_boxsizer.ShowItems(False)

        ## Add content to sizers
        self.hbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        vbox1 = wx.StaticBoxSizer(wx.StaticBox(self.panel, -1, label='Vbox1'), wx.VERTICAL)

        for btn in set1:
            vbox1.Add(btn, flag=wx.ALL, border=5)
        vbox1.Add(self.remove_cols_button)
        self.hbox.Add(vbox1, flag=wx.ALL, border=5)

        # add "grid"
        self.grid_box = wx.StaticBoxSizer(wx.StaticBox(self.panel, -1, name='grid container'), wx.VERTICAL)
        filler = wx.StaticBox(self.panel, wx.ID_ANY, "FillerStaticBox", size=(500, 200))
        self.grid_box.Add(filler, 1, flag=wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, border=5)
        # final layout, set size
        self.main_sizer.Add(self.hbox, flag=wx.ALL|wx.ALIGN_CENTER|wx.SHAPED, border=20)
        self.main_sizer.AddSpacer(20)
        self.main_sizer.Add(self.toggle_help_btn, .5,
                            flag=wx.BOTTOM|wx.ALIGN_CENTRE|wx.SHAPED,
                            border=5)
        self.main_sizer.Add(self.help_msg_boxsizer, .5,
                            flag=wx.BOTTOM|wx.ALIGN_CENTRE|wx.SHAPED,
                            border=10)
        self.main_sizer.AddSpacer(10)

        self.main_sizer.Add(self.grid_box, 2, flag=wx.ALL|wx.ALIGN_CENTER|wx.EXPAND, border=10)
        self.panel.SetSizer(self.main_sizer)
        self.panel_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.panel_sizer.Add(self.panel, 1)
        self.SetSizer(self.panel_sizer)
        self.panel_sizer.Fit(self)
        self.Centre()
        self.Show()


    def do_fit(self, event, min_size=None):
        """
        Re-fit the window to the size of the content.
        """
        if event:
            event.Skip()
        self.panel_sizer.Fit(self)
        self.Centre()
        return

    def toggle_help(self, event, mode=None):
        """
        Show/hide help message on help button click.
        """
        # if mode == 'open', show no matter what.
        # if mode == 'close', close.  otherwise, change state
        btn = self.toggle_help_btn
        shown = self.help_msg_boxsizer.GetStaticBox().IsShown()

        # if mode is specified, do that mode
        if mode == 'open':
            self.msg_text.SetSize(self.msg_text_size)
            self.help_msg_boxsizer.GetStaticBox().SetSize(self.msg_text_size)
            #self.help_msg_boxsizer.Fit(self.msg_text)
            self.help_msg_boxsizer.ShowItems(True)
            btn.SetLabel('Hide help')
        elif mode == 'close':
            self.help_msg_boxsizer.ShowItems(False)
            btn.SetLabel('Show help')
        # otherwise, simply toggle states
        else:
            if shown:
                self.help_msg_boxsizer.ShowItems(False)
                btn.SetLabel('Show help')
            else:
                self.msg_text.SetSize(self.msg_text_size)
                self.help_msg_boxsizer.GetStaticBox().SetSize(self.msg_text_size)
                #self.help_msg_boxsizer.Fit(self.msg_text)
                self.help_msg_boxsizer.ShowItems(True)
                btn.SetLabel('Hide help')

        self.do_fit(None)


    ##  Events

    def on_remove_cols(self, event):
        """
        enter 'remove columns' mode
        """
        self.remove_cols_mode = True
        self.remove_cols_button.SetLabel("end delete column mode")
        self.remove_cols_button.SetSize(self.remove_cols_button.GetBestSize())
        # change button to exit the delete columns mode
        self.Unbind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.remove_cols_button)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.exit_col_remove_mode, self.remove_cols_button)
        # then make some visual changes
        self.msg_text_size = (50, 50)
        self.msg_text.SetLabel("Remove grid columns: click on a column header to delete it.Required headers for {}s may not be deleted.".format(self.grid_type))
        self.toggle_help(event=None, mode='open')
        self.grid_box.GetStaticBox().SetWindowStyle(wx.DOUBLE_BORDER)

    def exit_col_remove_mode(self, event):
        """
        go back from 'remove cols' mode to normal
        """
        # close help messge
        self.toggle_help(event=None, mode='close')
        # update mode
        self.remove_cols_mode = False
        self.grid_box.GetStaticBox().SetWindowStyle(wx.DEFAULT)
        self.msg_text.SetLabel(self.default_msg_text)
        self.msg_text_size = (500, 150)
        self.help_msg_boxsizer.Fit(self.help_msg_boxsizer.GetStaticBox())
        self.toggle_help(None, mode='close')
        # re-bind self.remove_cols_button
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.on_remove_cols, self.remove_cols_button)
        self.remove_cols_button.SetLabel("Remove columns")
        self.do_fit(None)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App()
    frame = GridFrame()
    if '-i' in sys.argv:
        import wx.lib.inspection
        wx.lib.inspection.InspectionTool().Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not need any of that, as simply calling Layout on the parent, or one of the sizers up the hierarchy, when the text is changed should be sufficient.

In addition, I see that you set the `wx.SHAPED` flag when adding the `help_msg_boxsizer` to the `main_sizer`. That tells the parent sizer to keep the same aspect ratio that the item had when it was first added to the sizer, which is probably what is keeping that sizer and the static text from being sized greater than 0 pixels high.

Finally, you are using a proportion value of .5 in a couple places.  That parameter is an integer so it's just going to be truncated to zero and won't do what you are probably hoping it will. The way the proportion works is that the total sum of the proportion values in the sizer use used to calculate how the free space is divided up.  For example, if a box sizer has items with proportions of 1, 1, 2 then the first 2 get 25% of the free space each, and the third one gets 50%.